# How to list files of a directory in Android 6.0 ,Even if I tired many methods,It always retun null

Tags: java, android, file

I try to list files or files's name in android 6.0,but with many methods it always failed.First show the files in truth directory:

*Error 1:*
[image]

And I try to this way:

*Error 2:*
[image]

it dosen't work.and next way:

```
String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Music/";
    File file=new File(path);
    try {
        Log.d("file...info",file.isDirectory()+"");
        String[] files=file.list();
        Log.d("music...",files.length +"");
        PlayList=new ArrayList<>();
        for (String f:files){
            if (f.endsWith(".mp3")){
                PlayList.add(f);
                Log.d("music..........",f);
            }
        }
    }
```

then and this way:

```
    AssetManager mgr=getAssets();
    String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Music/";
    File file=new File(path);
    try {
        Log.d("file...info",file.isDirectory()+"");
        String[] files=mgr.list(path);
        Log.d("music...",files.length +"");
        PlayList=new ArrayList<>();
        for (String f:files){
            if (f.endsWith(".mp3")){
                PlayList.add(f);
                Log.d("music..........",f);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

even if i add permissions for it:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I also add these code :

```
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //申请WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE权限
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
```

Finally,I can't solve this problem.All above method could not get the files int directory .help me.

Comment: You did not tell what exactly fails or what happens instead.

Comment: @greenapps The directory in question  has 3 mp3 files,but I can't list them  by an array.It always return a null array,no mp3 files.

Comment: If list() would return null then your app would crash. You need to adapt your code for it. Moreover you did not tell what the Log statements print. Please tell the full path and tell how you checked that files are there.